# In a T-SQL table of prizes awarded, how can I find all users that received two specific prizes?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, relational-division

*This is not homework - it's based on a real problem I'm working on, but I've changed up the column names and values to create an MCVE.*

I have a table of entries, where each row is a record of a prize won by a user. For sake of discussion, `User` is an integer value and `Prize` is a string. I'm using [T-SQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transact-SQL).

| User | Prize |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Gold |
| 1 | Silver |
| 1 | Bronze |
| 2 | Bronze |
| 3 | Gold |
| 4 | Silver |

I'd like to get a list of Users that have won *both* a `Gold` prize and a `Silver` prize.

I've started by filtering to entries containing Gold or Silver, but I'm not sure how to do "AND" here.

```sql
SELECT * FROM Entries WHERE Prize LIKE 'Gold' OR Prize LIKE 'Silver'
```

If I replace `OR` with `AND`, I expect get nothing as `Prize` is only one or the other. I *could* just get the list of `Silver` and `Gold` recpipients, and use Python to do this:

1. Load two query results
2. Create `User` object for all user IDs present in either query
3. For each user ID, iterate over each table, and record if they're present in both or not
4. Export the list of users in both

However, I'm not sure how I can do that in SQL. Ideally, this would be my "result":

| User |
| --- |
| 1 |

How can I get a list of Users that have won Gold and Silver prizes (it's fine if they've gotten other prizes, too)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One canonical approach uses aggregation:

```sql
SELECT User
FROM Entries
WHERE Prize IN ('Silver', 'Gold')
GROUP BY User
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Prize) = 2;
-- HAVING MIN(Prize) <> MAX(Prize)
```

I have given an alternative `HAVING` clause above for this query which might be sargable and more performant.

Comment: Wouldn't this show a user with 2 Golds or 2 Silvers as well? Although OP doesn't mention it, I think that might a probable case in a table like this.

Comment: `it's fine if they've gotten other prizes, too` ... the OP did not mention your edge case, but it seems that this edge case would not be a concern.

Comment: The `DISTINCT Prize` seems takes care of the case where a single user might have the same prize twice. Tested it in a fiddle https://sqlfiddle.com/sql-server/online-compiler?id=91daf5ef-c5be-4519-af15-8724a476d604

Comment: @V.S The `Silver` and `Gold` would be the minimum, so a user with 2x Gold should not be included, but if they had 2x Gold _and_ 1x Silver, that would be perfectly fine.

Comment: Would I just need the code in the answer for that? Or would I want `>=` instead of `=`...?

Comment: @cocomac My current (accepted) answer already meets your requirements as you have stated them in the comments here.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your index structure and distribution, this may lead to two seeks instead of a full table/CIX scan, and may also be a bit easier to grok:

```
SELECT UserId FROM dbo.Entries 
  WHERE Prize = 'Gold'
INTERSECT
SELECT UserId FROM Entries 
  WHERE Prize = 'Silver';
```

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/nVjrNJJY)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a join for this:

```
SELECT p1.[user] FROM prizes p1 INNER JOIN
prizes p2 ON p1.[user] = p2.[user] 
AND p1.prize='Gold' AND p2.prize = 'Silver'
GROUP BY p1.[user]
```